# Microsoft Exchange Active Sync issue when roaming

Tags: sync, outlook, roaming, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I bought new Samsung Galaxy Note 2, Last week I went to a different state ( roaming). During roaming my office outlook mail is not syncing. Whole purpose of having Email on phone is gone. I don't think it's problem with the device/service provider. Gmail ,yahoo or internet is working without any issues. I was able to read emails on my other phone (iphone 3g) without issues (when roaming).
Can someone help me on this?

Comment: I believe this issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in the Android OS. A senior AT&T engineer let me know that this is a problem and hopefully it will be fixed soon.

it is not a AT&T, Verizon or T-Mobile issue. it is a problem with Android  :(

edit: he let me know that there is an app on the google store  called "Touchdown" that is a workaround for this issue.